# Where are the gnome panel launcher logs?

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-panel

I started adding shell-scripts as launcher to the Gnome panel, and it works like a charm.

However, occasionally stuff in the scripts fail. When the script is launched from a terminal there is a whole bunch of output showing the error and other non-error messages which are very useful to debug whatever is going on…

Where do these end up when the script is launched from a panel launcher?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably to [redirect the output](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) from within the scripts you add as launchers.